# Can I use a controller and view from a dll loaded after the application has started?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is it possible to use a controller and views from a dll loaded after the application has started?

All the examples I've found load the assembly before the application runs, but I would load assemblies *after* a user log in to the application depending on the permissions the user has.

Comment: This misunderstands a key tenet of how web apps work:  *every user is sharing the same code*. It's not user A has one process and user B has another. The application loads once for all of the users. You can still use language features like inheritance/polymorphism/interfaces to control what different user roles can see and do, but all those types are loaded into the app and available.

Comment: Looks like you searching for Role-based authorization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Then at one point you will simply have also all assemblies in memory and as web application tend to run constantly it will stay that way (there is no unload) . What do you think you gain by deferring loading to some time later.

Comment: OK I see your point, thank you very much

Comment: As other one said, we couldn't load part of dll. If you need authorize, we could use the policy or role authorize to just allow specific users to access the application.